# Equivalents of Nginx Ingress Annonations on IstIO Ingress Gateway

Tags: kubernetes, istio, nginx-ingress

I'm currently migrating an IT environment from Nginx Ingress Gateway to IstIO Ingress Gateway on Kubernetes.

I need to migrate the following Nginx annotations:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost
```

For Nginx, the annotations are documented here: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/

I didn't find the way of use for the IstIO Ingress Gateway on the documentation of IstIO for the Nginx annotations.

Does anyone know how to implement the above mentioned annotations in the IstIO Ingress Gateway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found how to set [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#proxy-body-size) in Istio.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: reviews-lua
  namespace: bookinfo
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: reviews
  configPatches:
    # The first patch adds the lua filter to the listener/http connection manager
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
      listener:
        portNumber: 8080
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
            subFilter:
              name: "envoy.router"
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value: # lua filter specification
       name: envoy.lua
       config:
         inlineCode: |
           function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
             request_handle:headers():add("request_body_size", request_handle:body():length())
           end
```

And also the TLS ciphers:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-tls-ingress
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-tls-ingress-gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    hosts:
    - "*"
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /etc/certs/server.pem
      privateKey: /etc/certs/privatekey.pem
      cipherSuites: "<tls-ciphers>"
```

Comment: did this work for you? for me it gives 
``` [string "function envoy_on_request(request_handle)..."]:3: attempt to index a nil value```
on get request and no header shows up on post request and returns http error 413

Answer (score 1):

If you receiving the 413 Entity Too Large as a response the main issue of this situation is that one of the Envoy filters within the chain has a buffering.

The discussion about that you will find here: https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/2919

The initial values for that buffering on Envoy are set by the properties:

```
  http2_protocol_options:
    initial_stream_window_size: 65536 # 64 KiB
    initial_connection_window_size: 1048576 # 1 MiB
```

Source: https://www.bookstack.cn/read/envoyproxy-1.13/9a624d80e56eceef.md

You can override that buffer for the given workload (or globally) but you have to remember if you will increase too much there is a risk of the out of memory attacks.

Example filter which reconfigure it:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: my-service
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER
      match:
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
      patch:
        operation: MERGE
        value:
          typed_config:
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager"
            http2_protocol_options:
              initial_stream_window_size: 65536
              initial_connection_window_size: 10485760 # 10 MB
```

You will find more about Envoy Filers on the Istio documentation: https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/

Additional samples: https://github.com/istio/istio/wiki/EnvoyFilter-Samples

Answer (score 0):

Nginx ingress annotations equivalents can be implemented in Istio with [Envoy Filter](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/).

More specifically by using [HTTP Lua filter](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/lua_filter#config-http-filters-lua).

Example of envoy filter that has HTTP Lua filter:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: reviews-lua
  namespace: bookinfo
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: reviews
  configPatches:
    # The first patch adds the lua filter to the listener/http connection manager
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
      listener:
        portNumber: 8080
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
            subFilter:
              name: "envoy.router"
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value: # lua filter specification
       name: envoy.lua
       config:
         inlineCode: |
           function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
             -- Make an HTTP call to an upstream host with the following headers, body, and timeout.
             local headers, body = request_handle:httpCall(
              "lua_cluster",
              {
               [":method"] = "POST",
               [":path"] = "/acl",
               [":authority"] = "internal.org.net"
              },
             "authorize call",
             5000)
           end
  # The second patch adds the cluster that is referenced by the lua code
  # cds match is omitted as a new cluster is being added
  - applyTo: CLUSTER
    match:
      context: SIDECAR_OUTBOUND
    patch:
      operation: ADD
      value: # cluster specification
        name: "lua_cluster"
        type: STRICT_DNS
        connect_timeout: 0.5s
        lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
        hosts:
        - socket_address:
            protocol: TCP
            address: "internal.org.net"
            port_value: 8888
```

For example:

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size` could be achieved by `size = buffer:length()`.

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout` or
`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout` are custom timeouts which could be achieved by `httpCall(5000)`.

Full list of methods can be found [here](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/lua_filter#stream-handle-api).

Hope this helps.

---

Update:

After rereading nginx annotations `getBytes()` looks better for `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size` than `buffer:lenght()`.

> getBytes()
>
> buffer:getBytes(index, length)
>
> Get bytes from the buffer. By default Envoy will not copy all buffer
>   bytes to Lua. This will cause a buffer segment to be copied.  *index* 
>   is an integer and supplies the buffer start index to copy.  *length* 
>   is an integer and supplies the buffer length to copy.  *index*  + 
>   *length*  must be less than the buffer length.

So `buffer:getBytes(0, 8000)` should load 8k of bytes from buffer similar to `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "8k"`.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful, though it's very complicated in comparision to Nginx annotations.

Comment: Can you give an example on how to use `size = buffer:length()`? I don't get it from the documentation. I want to set the buffer size of the proxied server.

Comment: I have edited my answer addressing your additional question. Also fixed the first example. My examples are just suggestions I can't verify if they work.

Comment: Ok thanks. And how to implement `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size` in IstIO?

Comment: And how to implement annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-ciphers`in Istio?